# Get struct from function type

Tags: go, reflection, struct

I currently have the following code

```
func (r *Router) Get(path string, controller interface{}) {
    ...
    t := reflect.TypeOf(controller)
    ...
}
```

That is called doing the following

```
Route.Get("/", controllers.Test.IsWorking)
```

The second argument is basically this

```
type Test struct {
    *Controller
    Name string
}

func (t Test) IsWorking() {

}

type Controller struct {
    Method   string
    Request  *http.Request
    Response http.ResponseWriter
    Data     map[interface{}]interface{}
}
```

I want to get the struct the function refers to. create a new struct of that type and call the function so for example

controllers.Test.IsWorking

Create a Test struct and call IsWorking()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a new pointer to a newly allocated struct of the type in the interface, all you need is

```
newController := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(controller)).Interface()
```

Or to set a value on the new instance first:

```
newController := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(controller))
newController.Elem().FieldbyName("Method").Set(reflect.ValueOf("GET"))
```

If you want to create a pointer to a struct and call the `IsWorking` method, it looks like

```
t := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(Test{}))
t.MethodByName("IsWorking").Call(nil)
```

Comment: I dont think this is what I am looking for. or maybe it is but well. I want to get the struct the function is referring to, fill the fields of that struct and call the function that is being passed. This is to create a new controller and set the fields no? I mean this is also a part of what I am looking

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai: You said your method is not expecting a pointer, but you can't change the value of a struct if you don't have a pointer to it.

Comment: True I am a little bit off today. I dont want to edit the value of a struct but create it on runtime so when the function passes controllers.Test.IsWorking create a Test struct and call the Test.IsWorking function with the newly created struct wich I can set the fields I guess

Comment: Pleas show what your end goal is here. I don't understand what you're asking. Are you sure you need `reflect` for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I now updated main post. I am sure I need reflect since I dont know what struct I am passing

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. I added how to call a method by name on a new `*Test` value.

Comment: That is what I am looking for BUT without knowing about Test{} is that possible?

Comment: You don't need to know what `Test{}` is, the argument for `TypeOf` is `interface{}`, so just pass in the `interface{}` value.

Comment: Oh. Also what if I dont know about IsWorking? The above example wont work I am not passing Test{} as the interface but Test.IsWorking maybe I should change what I am passing to make it easier?

Comment: It's definitely easier if you know _something_ about the method you want to call.

Comment: I dont think I am able to know more about it.

Comment: You must know something if you want to call a method, the name, the signature, etc. BTW, if you know the signature, it's much easier to call a method via an interface type assertion than with reflection.

Comment: Okey I think I can pass the controller and the function name as two arguments for the function that might work. thanks